# `next build` and `npm run build` fail with different errors, but deploy fine on vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I currently have a Next.js website that I want to run `next build` on. However, when I run `next build`, I get:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
```

I've went to Next.js's website that was linked in the error message but no luck.

What's even more strange is that when I run `npm run build`, which should be the exact same thing as `next build`, because my package.json is:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
```

I get a different error when I run `npm run build`:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/constants.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/.next/server/pages/_document.js
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
- /Users/ganningxu/programming/programming_ncssm/CyberUnicorns/cyberunicorns_website/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
```

However, when I deploy my app through Vercel's dashboard, they're also building the website through `next build` and it succeeds. I'm not really sure what the issue is here? Seems like something wrong with `next` on my local computer.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing your node-modules?

Comment: Also, have you tried implementing possible fixes adressed in https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error ? Could you please share a code inside of the / && /505 && /404 page?

Comment: I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling all the node modules, no help sadly

Comment: Also the error code for all of them was 321 (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321). I've tried the fixes on the prerender link but its not having an effect it seems

Comment: But in my code, i'm not even using any react hooks, which is confusing me

Comment: Hi, sorry for long delay, could you please post your project structure here? Or, if this is open source, send a github link?

Comment: No worries! Here is the GitHub (https://github.com/CyberUnicorns/CyberUnicorns.github.io). I was able to successfully run `npm run build && next export` once, which is why I have the `out` folder, but when I try to do `npm run build` again, it just fails. I didn't change anything in the code

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. After adding `framer-motion` to the project's dependencies, I was able to successfully build the app. This might indicate the issue isn't with the code, but with some local setup/configuration on your machine.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot reproduce the issue either. I just cloned your repo and tried to build last 3 commits. All builds were successfull. Do you still experience this issue @GanningXu? If I were you, I would just try to reinstall node, I know it's not the best solution, but I am like 90% certain that it will work :/

Comment: Aha! Uninstalling and reinstalling worked! Thank you so much for your help